# Error usando ORM de cakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

Hola amigos tengo un error, cuando intento consultar una información a la BD no me trae los datos de una tabla y me da un error.

```
public function ejercicio1()
    {
        $data = $this->fetchTable('Users')->find()->join([
        'table' => 'Roles',
        'alias' => 'rol',
        'type' => 'left',
        'conditions' => 'Roles.id = Users.roles_id'
        ])->select(["Users.id", "Users.nombres"]);
        
        
   
       $this->set(compact('data'));
    }
```

Error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El mensaje de error es muy claro: `La tabla Roles no existe`.

Comment: Pero es que cuando yo hago un select from con la tabla Roles si funciona en el controllador me trae información y todo, entonces no se en donde esta el fallo ya que la conexion entre el modelo y el controlador si esta

Comment: $data2 = $this->fetchTable('Roles')->find()->all(); esta es la consulta que hago y si funciona

Comment: ¿Qué versión de CakePHP estás usando?

Comment: la version 4 de cakePHP